# How to find out the installed packages which have unmet dependencies?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I'm frequently getting this error in notification on top right corner. Though I have tried to run `sudo apt-get check` but no installed packages found which have unmet dependencies.

An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt- get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: 'Error: Opening the cache (E:can not open /var/lib/apt/lists/ security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal- security InRelease-Fopen (13: Permission denied), E.The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies

Comment: This usually means you are not running the command with `sudo`

Comment: Follow the instructions provided by your output: Run the command in a terminal window. Copy the entire input and output from the terminal window. Paste that complete output into your question.